# Draining the entropy of std::random_device

Tags: c++, random, g++, entropy

I'm using `std::random_device` and would like to check for its remaining entropy. According to cppreference.com:

> ## [`std::random_device::entropy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy)
>
> ```
> double entropy() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> #### Return value
>
> The value of the device entropy, or zero if not applicable.
>
> #### Notes
>
> This function is not fully implemented in some standard libraries. For example, LLVM libc++ always returns zero even though the device is non-deterministic. In comparison, Microsoft Visual C++ implementation always returns 32, and boost.random returns 10.
>
> The entropy of the Linux kernel device /dev/urandom may be obtained using ioctl RNDGETENTCNT - that's what std::random_device::entropy() in GNU libstdc++ uses as of version 8.1

So under Linux ang g++ >= 8.1, I should be good... but I'm not:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

void drain_entropy(std::random_device& rd, std::size_t count = 1)
{
    while (count --> 0) {
        volatile const int discard = rd();
        (void) discard;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::cout << "Entropy: " << rd.entropy() << '\n'; // Entropy: 32
    drain_entropy(rd, 1'000'000);
    std::cout << "Entropy: " << rd.entropy() << '\n'; // Entropy: 32
}
```

[Live demo on Coliru (which runs under Linux, right?)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85d17db7e6cdf3e7)

I'm expecting that generating numbers from the device drains its entropy. But it doesn't.

What's happening?

Comment: Just because the Linux kernel supports querying the remaining entropy in its random number generator doesn't mean that 1) the C++ library uses the kernel's random number generator, and/or 2) the C++ library meaningfully implements returning the remaining entropy.

Comment: @Sam cppreference claims 1) and 2) are true.

Comment: @YSC what is the problem? I don't see any here.

Comment: @DanM. I'm expecting that generating number from the device drain its entropy. It doesn't. (Q fixed)

Comment: @YSC why would you think that reading 1 million ints would decrease it in any meaningful way? It's probably generated way faster than that. On my local machine I had to start draining `10^10` of bytes for it to decrease in a meaningful way.

Comment: Modern CPU has RDRAND instruction which can generate random values quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library will not return an entropy value greater than the number of bits in its result type, which is 32 in this case.

See [libstd code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/random.cc#L194-L196):

```
const int max = sizeof(result_type) * __CHAR_BIT__;
if (ent > max)
  ent = max;
```

The documentation you linked to explains this:

> Obtains an estimate of the random number device entropy, which is a floating-point value between 0 and log 2(max()+1) (which is equal to std::numeric_limits::digits).

Comment: I though 32 (`std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits`) was the maximum entropy, not the maximum value of the return value :D

Answer (score 0):

You can see how `.entropy()` is implemented [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/random.cc#L177).

Basically, the `entropy()` calls `ioctl(fd, RNDGETENTCNT, &ent)` and returns `ent` (after clamping it the maximum number of bits in the target type as required).

It just so happens that it didn't change after your `drain_entropy` call.

You can manually implement this method and see that it behaves the same.
Even if you remove the clamping, the entropy is barely affected (it could even increase).